# Tor Expert Bundle exit node is blocked but Tor Browser is not

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, cloudflare

I'm trying to access a website that is blocking Tor users by CloudFlare. When I use Tor as a service using chrome browser my exit node is always blocked. However, using Tor browser sometimes CloudeFlare don't block my exit node, so I decided to use my exit node ip that my Tor browser uses (the one that is not blocked by CloudFlare) and set it in the `torrc` file of my Tor expert bundle

```
ExitNodes  89.163.143.8
```

My "brilliant idea" didn't work!. CloudFlare still blocks chrome browser and allows Tor browser although they use the exact same exit node.

So what is happening? does CloudFlare use different techniques to block certain users other than exit nodes lists?

Comment: Cloudflare blocks connections from the Tor network that don't come from the Tor Browser. In this case, Chrome and the Tor Browser behave slightly differently, and Cloudflare can tell that you're not connecting from the Tor Browser so they block you.

Comment: @Steve Do you know why wouldn't CloudFlare block Tor browser connections?

Comment: Cloudflare doesn't want to block all Tor users, only those using the Tor network maliciously (attempting attacks, scraping, etc), so they've decided to allow Tor Browser users but block all other clients. I'm guessing that they use some fingerprint of the connection handshake to identify if someone is using the Tor Browser or not.